# Laravel 4 hosting in cPanel

Tags: php, laravel-4, xampp, cpanel

I am new to php. I've completed a project in Laravel and now I want to move it to a cPanel based server. I've used xampp in my development machine and it works just fine. I've edited the paths and index.php. It shows the login page. When I enter user name and password it redirects back to the login page. I've tried a lot but with no luck solving the problem.

**htaccess file**

```
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_ConfigPath /opt/phpcur/lib
</IfModule>



# Use PHPcur as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-phpcur .php
```

Comment: @Prisoner > If you are talking about browser cache Yes I cleared that.

Comment: Is the database setup? Are you receiving any errors? Do you have debug enabled?

Comment: @SamMonk > No, I am not receiving any error. After entering username and password it just redirect to login page again.

Comment: Try rehashing the password, to make sure that you have the correct credentials.

Comment: @SamMonk> I've already a hashed password. And I feels like i've a routing problem may be. My login page look OK. when I enter username and password it just redirect to login page again. :(

Comment: Check the htaccess file and see if there are any issues.

Comment: @dom > See my htaccess file content in edit.

Comment: @dom > Please let me know if I am missing something. :(

Answer (score 0):

Where is that htaccess located? /public?

Check out the htaccess on the laravel documentation website. Try these implementations:
http://laravel.com/docs/installation

Comment: What I did is: while creating the project for the first time I moved all content of the public folder to its parent folder. Now I copied everything to the cPanel's public_html folder.